# setState is changed but the variable assigned to it can not get the updated value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, loading, use-effect, use-state

developing a chat app with a loader to wait until receiving the response. According to console.log in the app the `isLoading` state changes correctly however inside the receiver's object the `isLoaded` key is not gonna getting update and only show the initial value of the assigned state. As a result the loader doesn't show in the UI. You can find the code below.

```
const [messagesList, setMessagesList] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [currentMessage, setCurrentMessage] = useState("");

  const handleSend = () => {
    if (currentMessage !== "") {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setMessagesList([
        ...messagesList,
        {
          dataType: "text",
          item: {
            id: uuidv4(),
            type: "sender",
            message: currentMessage,
          },
        },
      ]);
      axios
        .post(`${BASE_URL}`, {
          data: currentMessage,
        })
        .then((response) => {          
          setIsLoading(false);
          setMessagesList([
            ...messagesList,
            {
              dataType: "text",
              item: {
                id: uuidv4(),
                type: "sender",
                message: currentMessage,
              },
            },
            {
              dataType: "text",
              item: {
                id: uuidv4(),
                type: "reciever",
                isLoaded: isLoading,
                message: response.data.data.answers
              },
            },
          ]);
          setCurrentMessage("");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setIsLoading(true);
          setMessagesList([
            ...messagesList,
            {
              dataType: "text",
              item: {
                id: uuidv4(),
                type: "sender",
                message: currentMessage,
              },
            },
            {
              dataType: "text",
              item: {
                id: uuidv4(),
                type: "reciever",
                isLoaded: isLoading,
                message: "something went wrong"
              },
            },
          ]);
          setCurrentMessage("");
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
      setCurrentMessage("");
    } 
  };

return (
<>
       <textarea
        type="text"
         placeholder="ask me ..."
         rows={1}
         cols={1}  
         onChange={(e) => setCurrentMessage(e.target.value)}
         value={currentMessage}    
         autoFocus
 />
<button onClick={ ()=> handleSend }> Sned </button>

   {messagesList.map(({ dataType, item }) => {
                if (dataType === "text") {
                  if (item.type === "sender") {
                    return (
                      <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{item.message}</p>
                    );
                  }
                  if (item.type === "reciever") {
                    if (item.isLoaded) {
                      return <p> laoding</p>;
                    } else {
                      return <p> {item.message} </p>;
                    }
                  }
                }
              })}
</>
    
)
```

Comment: There are no console.logs in the snippet you published.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here likely stems from the fact that you are using the value of `isLoading` right after setting it via `setLoading`.

Setting the state in React acts like an async function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and try to use it's value right after,
you will likely get the previous value of that state.

In this case, try to make the relevant `messagesList` values independent of `isLoading`.

**Example:**

```
.then((response) => {
  const newIsLoading = false;
  setIsLoading(newIsLoading);
  setMessagesList([
    ...messagesList,
    {
      // Some code...
    },
    {
      dataType: "text",
      item: {
        id: uuidv4(),
        type: "reciever",
        isLoaded: newIsLoading,
        message: response.data.data.answers
      },
    },
  ]);
  setCurrentMessage("");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

State updates are dispatched asyncronously. That means that by the time your code reaches your second `setMessagesList`, that is the last one considered and thus dispatched.

```
setMessagesList([...]) // to be dispatched
axios.post((resp)=> resp.json().then(data=> setMessagesList([...]) //oops, not that one, this one
```

Probably, your console.log has to do with that. If you want to see the updated value, you will need to add it as an **effect**

```
useEffect(()=> console.log(messagesList), [messagesList])
```

Lastly, you may want to move shared code by `.then` and `.catch` to a `.finally`:

```
.finally(()=> {
    setCurrentMessage("");
    setIsLoading(false);
}
```